# db table gets vanish automatically in code first entity framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I am new to entity framework , visual studio and .net. I have created model for db table (using code first conventions). I have run the migration and updated the table It works fine I insert and get the entities in table but it sometime my table and table data get vanishes . 
I have to run the `update-database` command to generate table again .
what could be the reason of vanishing the db tables . there is migration script present in my code here is my LMSSeedData class

```
public class LMSSeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LMSDBContext>
{
   protected override void Seed(LMSDBContext context)
    {

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

here is context class

```
public class LMSDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public LMSDBContext()
        : base("LMSDBContext")
    {



        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LMSDBContext>());

   Database.SetInitializer<LMSDBContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<LMSDBContext, Migrations.Configuration("LMSDBContext"));

        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
     }
  }
```

here is my packages.config file

```
<packages>
<package id="Edi.Web.MvcExtensions" version="5.2.3.1" 
targetFramework="net461" />
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0-beta1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
 </packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your DbContext class and the mapping class? We can only guess without those.

Do you have any database seeder like this:

```
public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContextName>
{
     protected override void Seed(YourContextName context)
     {
         // seed database here
         ......
     }
}
```

That initializer will drop and recreate the database and tables each time it runs.

You can read more about Database Initialization Strategies here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

If you don't want to recreate the database and tables, try use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` instead.

Again, you didn't post code so I have no idea what your classes and setups look like.

Comment: ys i have these 2 classes

Comment: I don't think the *database* disappears, but the description is to vague to give any proper answer.

Comment: the two tables that i made disappears with random behavior I have to run update database again and again .  can you please help me out ? @GertArnold

Comment: which code (dbcontext or model) u need i will upload it @David

Comment: The 'DbContext', 1 of the mapping configuration classes if you have any, and any db initializer class.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold actully me lead give me that code and I'm adding new feature on it . only table that i added vanishes not whole database

Comment: this class already added I didnt do anything with it @GertArnold

Comment: No, but didn't the very name of it ring a bell? It doesn't do anything because the second `Database.SetInitializer` call overrides it, but how can you even leave it there if you're maintaining existing code? Anyway, it's obvious now that your migrations are screwed up somewhere. I think you have to rebuild all migrations from scratch. There's an abundance of info on the internet how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your time can you give me a quick guide link to .net , entityframework and everything relating to it ? @GertArnold

Comment: It looks like you're using ASP.NET Identity framework. Can you tell me what version you're using? I have setup Identity framework before so maybe I can point you somewhere. @Asad

Comment: I have added packages.config file is it enough for u ? @DavidLiang

Comment: Awww I just can't reproduce your behavior.

Comment: problem still exists  :( @DavidLiang

Comment: I see you defined `LMSSeedData` class but don't see you're using it. Can you show the code for that as well?